# Returning multiple results from Python function for each variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to have multiple "sum" results, for multiple "a" and "b" variables in below example? If so, how?

```
def function(a,b):
    sum = a +b
    return sum
```

I want to assign multiple values for a and b, and then calculate result for each scenario.

for a between 1 and 10
for b between 1 and 10
return sum for all those combinations of a and b values (100 combinations should be listed separately)

Is there any other way other than manually writing each scenario?

Comment: Note that it is not best practice to name a variable `sum` as it is the name of a predefined function.

Comment: Use a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept an iterable to your function and collect values from loops over both iterables.

```
def function(a,b):
    result = []
    for el_a in a:
        for el_b in b:
            result.append(el_a + el_b)
    return result

a = range(5)
b = range(5)

print(function(a,b))
```

Comment: you would need to add +1 to the ranges

Comment: @minattosama I don't consider that as part of the solution - whatever numbers you want added, you put them in the lists, whether they are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` function works the same.

Comment: It depends on how you understand the question

Comment: Thank you for your help, this code works for me! Also this answers my real problem: "accept an iterable to your function and collect values from loops over both iterables"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
def function(a, b):
    sums = []
    for num1 in range(a+1):
        for num2 in range(b+1):
            s = num1 + num2
            sums.append(s)
    return sums
```

Example you mentioned can be calculated as: `function(10, 100)`

Edit: using `range(a+1)` and `range(b+1)` will allow you to explicitly include 10 and 100 in this calculation.

Comment: you would need to add +1 to the ranges

Comment: I found it unclear if this is what the asker wanted; but, more often than not, you are probably correct @minattosama ! Edited accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_funct(a,b):
    sum_dict = {}
    for a_ in range(a+1):
        for b_ in range(b+1):
            s_ = a_ + b_
            sum_dict[str(a_)+"+"+str(b_)] = s_
    return sum_dict
```

Something like this ? You'll get also the operation in the key if needed

```
sum_funct(2,2)
>>> {'0+0': 0,
 '0+1': 1,
 '0+2': 2,
 '1+0': 1,
 '1+1': 2,
 '1+2': 3,
 '2+0': 2,
 '2+1': 3,
 '2+2': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way other than manually writing each scenario?

You might harness [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as follows

```
import itertools
def function(a,b):
    return sum(i*j for i,j in itertools.product(a,b))
print(function([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

gives output

```
3025
```